# About lists in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have an excel file with a column in which values are in multiple rows in this format 25/02/2016. I want to save all this rows of dates in a list. Each row is a separate value. How do I do this? So far this is my code:

I have an excel file with a column in which values are in multiple rows in this format 25/02/2016. I want to save all this rows of dates in a list. Each row is a separate value. How do I do this? So far this is my code:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook ('LOTERIAREAL.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
rowsnum = sheet.get_highest_row()
wholeNum = []
for n in range(1, rowsnum):
    wholeNum = sheet.cell(row=n, column=1).value

print (wholeNum[0])
```

When I use the print statement, instead of printing the value of the first row which should be the first item in the list e.g.  25/02/2016, it is printing the first character of the row which is the number 2. Apparently it is slicing thru the date. I want the first row and subsequent rows saved as separate items in the list. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`wholeNum = sheet.cell(row=n, column=1).value` assigns the value of the cell to the variable wholeNum, so you're never adding anything to the initial empty list and just overwrite the value each time. When you call `wholeNum[0]` at the end, wholeNum is a the last string that was read, and you're getting the first character of it.

You probable want `wholeNum.append(sheet.cell(row=n, column=1).value)` to accumulate a list.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> wholeNum =
> ```

This is an assignment.  It makes the name `wholeNum` refer to whatever object the expression to the right of the `=` operator evaluates to.

> ```
> for ...:
>     wholeNum = ...
> ```

Performing assignment in a loop is frequently not useful.  The name `wholeNum` will refer to whatever value was assigned to it in the last iteration of the loop.  The other iterations have no discernible effect.

To append values to a list, use the [`.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method.

```
for ...:
    wholeNum.append( ... )

print( wholeNum )
print( wholeNum[0] )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I try to use append as suggested , the following message shows up: wholeNum.append = (sheet.cell(row=n, column=1).value)
AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only

Comment: @moremon the correct use is `wholeNum.append(sheet.cell(row=n, column=1).value)`